# Maskedtextbox input doesn't work properly after focus

Tags: vb.net, maskedtextbox

I have a problem with maskedtextbox on focus. After second character is entered first one is overwritten. It **doesn't** happen only when form is loaded, after that every time when it's focused.
To illustrate this better :

This is how it should look when text is enetered
[image: This is how it should look when text is inputed]

And this is how it look when second character is entered:
[image][image]

I gave up on maskedtextboxes because of that, but now I have no choice.

I've tried with select, position and nothing helps so far.

Comment: I tried to reproduce that scenario but I think nothing is wrong with mine.

Comment: It happens to me every time, maybe it's because of the mask : MaskedTextBox1.Mask = "##.##.####."

Comment: I think you are using Visual Studio 2008. Am I right?

Comment: No, Visual Express 2013